# jquery plugin doesn't work on html replace

Tags: jquery

When I replace html inside `container` jquery plugin stops reacting on event (fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vfDKj/7/)

```
(function($) {

    jQuery.fn.myTest = function(){
        var $this = jQuery(this);
        $this.on('keyup', function(){
            $(this).after('<div>event</div>');
        })
        return this;
    }

}(jQuery));    
$(".test").myTest();
var html = $("#container").html();
$("#container").html(html);
```

I know, I can reinit but I need to make it work wihtout reinit. Is that possible?

Comment: You have an unbalanced parenthesis in the line : `}(jQuery));`.  It should be `})(jQuery);`.

Answer (score 1):

You're replacing the dom element. You need to "reinit" resp. you need to bind the event to the newly created element. Another way would be to simply alter and re-append dom elements, but from within your question its not possible to exactly guess why you would need to change the html itself.

Comment: I need this for ajax search back button.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(function($) {

$.fn.myTest = function(){
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    $this.on('keyup', ".test", function(){
        $(this).after('<div>event</div>');
    })
    return this;
}

})(jQuery);    /* edit: there was an unbalanced paren here */
$("#container").myTest();
var html = $("#container").html();
$("#container").html(html);
```

The main difference here is how I'm calling `$this.on`; see the second argument. This uses delegated events.

Edit: I didn't point this out but the second crucial part is the wrapped set that I'm applying the plugin to: `#container`.

From the [documentation for jquery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time
```

Comment: Yours applied `myTest` to a different wrapped set than mine: `$("#container")`.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/vfDKj/23/

Comment: For some reason, jsfiddle is not working for me.  Try copying the updated code in the box above. I fixed an unbalanced parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

You could eventually use detach this way:

http://jsfiddle.net/vfDKj/8/

```
$(".test").myTest();
var html = $("#container *").detach();
$("#container").html(html);
```

Comment: I am not sure if the events are then still bound?

Comment: sure they are, just check jsffiddle and doc:  The .detach() method is the same as .remove(), except that .detach() keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements. This method is useful when removed elements are to be reinserted into the DOM at a later time

Comment: i know what detach does, but i am not sure about the .html() functions, which may create NEW html rather than appending the detached ones. but good solution :)

Comment: @Alex ya, i was just wondering if you were talking about the html() method instead, sorry at first i was thinking you told about detach() method